# 3 Terabyte hard drives in Mac Pro Mid 2010?

Tags: hard-drive, mac-pro

I got the Mid 2010 Single CPU Mac Pro and want to add a 3 TB hard drive, specifically the Western Digital Caviar Green WD30EZRX.

Does anyone know if that drive will work? Not looking to boot from it, just need a large data drive and got all 4 bays in use already.

Mac is running OS X Lion and windows 7 64-Bit, so GPT partition scheme is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

If it fits the in Sata slot, it works.

Comment: Have you tried it? Hard drives over 2 TB have serious compatibility issues in the Wintel world, for example with file systems (limited to 2 TB), boot loaders (not able to boot on partitions over 2 TB) and controllers (only detecting a 3TB drive as 746GB on some Sandy Bridge mainboards). Since my Mac Pro is based on the older X58 chipset I'm not so certain that the SATA Controller supports it, and I can only hope that 64-Bit EFI can boot from it, and that Mac OS X can read it in exFAT, NTFS and/or HFS+.

Comment: well there are limitations with wintel file systems (fat32 in particular) but other than that ur good to go

Comment: HFS+ will support 8EB (that 8,000 Petabytes or 8,000,000 TB).  NTFS has the same amount of support.  SATA can support 130EB (if I remember correctly).  A 2TB drive, as long as it fits will work.

Answer (score 0):

No issue with 3GB, at 6GB you need a different bracket. The drives are the same size but mounting holes are different.